# Split String based on the String and patterns - Updated

Tags: java

```
String prop="AS=AP:BS=BP:CS=CS:DS=DPS:";
String currentValue="AS"
```

I have the above string value(prop), i want to split the String based on the String value(currentValue) and print the value between the Equal and Colon sign.
So i have used the below code to achieve this, but its failing in for the last string value "DSP" Since it's length is 3

`System.out.println(prop.substring((prop.indexOf(geo)+3), (prop.indexOf(geo)+5)));`

I'm an Unix Engineer used `awk` to achive this in a UNIX script, Is there any way to achieve this as a one liner in JAVA?

Update : the below code is working fine but its failing when both values are equal, like AS=AS:BS=BS:CS=CP:DS=DPS: when currentValue is AS/BS its failing
`String subStr=prop.split(currentValue)[1];` 
`System.out.println(subStr.substring(subStr.indexOf("=")+1,subStr.indexOf(":")));`

Comment: OK, so you are used to regular expressions, right? Then read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ and use them in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking this kind of solution?

```
String prop="AS=AP:BS=BP:CS=CP:DS=DPS:";
String currentValue="AS";

String subStr=prop.split(currentValue)[1]; 
System.out.println(subStr.substring(subStr.indexOf("=")+1,subStr.indexOf(":")));
```

Comment: No i have tried this, when the currentValue="DS" the output is DP. But i want the output as DPS

Comment: @Marjer yes This will print what you want... I have edited.. try `currentValue` as `DS`

Comment: Hi its failing when both values are equal, like AS=AS:BS=BS:CS=CP:DS=DPS: when currentvalue is AS/BS its failing

Comment: @Marjer yes.. It should fail in that case.... then you need to go for another option..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86679/discussion-between-marjer-and-ruchira-gayan-ranaweera).